# Deleted Service Application, Service Instance(s) Remain

Tags: user-profile, central-administration, profile-sync, user-profile-service

The User Profile Synchronization Service was not properly configured and was stuck in "Stopping" state. I was able to delete the User Profile Service Application but the User Profile Service (instance) and User Profile Synchronization Service remained. How do I get rid of them all so I can start fresh with the User Profile Service configuration?

**Edit:** I've tried [this](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx#ups14) along with many other posts I've found. I'm looking for a way to perhaps manually delete this or at least set the status to "Stopped."

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not sure if this has been tried since there's a bout 50 million things to try on Harbar's site (Good site though)

I always do the following if the actual Service is stuck in Stopping or Starting:

Firstly, run this:

```
Get-SPServiceInstance
```

This will show a list of service Instances. Find your broken Service (Status will be Provisioning or Unprovisioning)

Get the GUID of this Service

Next

```
$srvc = Get-SPServiceInstance "GUID"
$srvc.Unprovision()
```

WAIT...

WAIT SOME MORE....

HOPE....

WAIT...

It stopped!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow the instructions in Spence Harbar's ["Stuck on Starting"](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx#ups14) article, and specifically the section on resetting the synchronization service instance.

Comment: I've actually tried that exact method already. Sorry I didn't mention it but I've tried a lot of things, most of which I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to look in the SP_Config database and find the `object` which related to the unprovisioning of the User Profile Synchronization Service. After deleting that object I was able to:

```
$s = Get-SPServiceInstance <GUID of User Profile Synchronization Service>
$s.Delete()
```

And the service was deleted. Now I can start "fresh," in theory.

Comment: OUCH... You shouldn't have deleted it.... Now you'll see the Service Instance is gone... completely gone... I did that the other day and I think the only way to get it back was to run the Sharepoint Installer and do a repair...

Comment: I haven't seen the consequences yet, I'll report back once I do.