# User Profile Service Not working

Tags: user-profile-service, central-administration, service, forefront

I will try to be as specific as possible.

I have deleted User Profile Service Application, and remade it many times. I think the first two times i Deleted the Synchronization first, and then the Application. (don't know if that matters)

Every time I Start User Profile Synchronization Service, it says Starting.
When I go to Services and check FIM. FIM service says disabled. FIM Synchronization switches from disabled to automatic.

When I run the Powershell command.

```
     get-spserviceinstance | where {$_.TypeName -eq "User Profile Service"}
```

I get...

```
 TypeName                         Status           Id                                  
 --------                          ------           --                                  
User Profile Service             Online        d8d1bed3-11be-4e42-b95d-27923dd6f794
User Profile Service             Disabled      e9f685dd-0fab-4782-8a21-470c5fb6fb5f
```

After a few minutes Both FIM's are disabled, and the powershell script returns both Disabled. Central Admin will then show the Synchronization as Stopped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all the instances and try fresh I recommend the following solution:

[Deleted Service Application, Service Instance(s) Remain](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16146/deleted-service-application-service-instances-remain)

This issue can also be resolved with following PowerShell Script:

============================================

```
# Loads the SharePoint 2010 PowerShell extensions 
Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell  

# Sets variable for User Profile Service Application: enter the name of your UPA in quotes, replacing the "UPA" example
$upa = Get-SPServiceApplication |?{$_.displayname -eq "UPA"}

# Sets variable for service instance: enter your User Profile Synchonization Service instance ID/GUID in quotes
# which can be found by running "Get-SPServiceInstance" in PowerShell manually and copying the ID
$profsync = Get-SPServiceInstance |?{$_.id -eq "382e333c-61f0-4107-ac5f-31aaf0a3aec3"}

# Sets variables for farm account and password: enter your password in quotes
$farmacctpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -String "Password1" -Force
$farmacct = (get-spfarm).defaultserviceaccount

# Sets variable for synchronization server: enter your server name in quotes
$syncServer = "SharePoint1"
if($profsync.Status -eq "disabled")
{
  Write-Host "Provisioning User Profile Synchronization Service"
  $upa.SetSynchronizationMachine($syncServer, $profsync.ID, $farmacct.LookupName(), $farmacctpwd)
}
else
{ 
  write-host "Profile Synchronization Service is"$profsync.Status
}
```

Share The outcome if this helps

Comment: What do you mean by variable for synchronization server? I used the IP address of the SQL Server instance when configuring the farm. Or are you asking for which server you want the Synchronization service to run?

Comment: SharePoint Server Which is running the Sync Services and UPA