# Cannot delete User Profile Service in SP 2010

Tags: user-profile-service

I want to delete the User Profile Service Application in SP 2010. On Manage Service Application page I click Delete on the ribbon. But the popup keep showing "In Progress..." and never finish. The cpu keep running low seem not doing any task

I then using powershell to check the status of the upa, it showing "Unprovisioning"

What should I do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the actual Service is stuck in Stopping or Starting:

Firstly, run this:

```
Get-SPServiceInstance
```

This will show a list of service Instances. Find your broken Service (Status will be Provisioning or Unprovisioning)

Get the GUID of this Service

Next

```
$srvc = Get-SPServiceInstance "GUID"
$srvc.Unprovision()
```

Wait for sometime it will stop

Verify that you have the following administrative credentials to delete UPA:

1. To use Central Administration to delete a User Profile Service application, you must be a member of the Farm Administrators group.
2. In the Delete Service Application dialog box, verify that you have selected the correct User Profile Service application to delete, select Delete data associated with the Service Applications to delete all data associated with the selected User Profile Service application, and then click OK.

Follow the instructions in [Stuck in Stop/Start](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx#ups14) article

Reference

[Delete UPA](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16146/deleted-service-application-service-instances-remain)

Comment: $srvc = Get-SPServiceInstance "GUID" return "Online"
$upa = Get-SPServiceApplication "GUID" give me "Unprovisioning"
 
should I work on the ServiceInstance or ServiceApplication?

Comment: You have to work with instance . Service application is the logical container of the service, what is exposed through Manage Service Applications. The service application endpoint is not created until an associated service machine instance is started. There can be more than one instance of a particular service application. 

 When the service is implemented these bits are deployed to every server in the farm when the install is performed. When PSConfig(UI).exe is run you will see the status: “Successfully installed Service Instance: name of service”.